# Enable mysqli in docker container

Tags: php, docker

I build some containers with the following code:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
    ports:
      - "9906:3306"
  web:
    image: php:7.3-apache
    container_name: php_web
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - "8100:80"
```

This works like a charm. The only problem what I have is that I need the mysqli module. This one is not included in the php:7.3-apache image.

So what I tried was to add this in the dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.3-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

That is not working. So how can I add the mysqli module to my container?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do this in your Dockerfile to enable MySQLi:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
```

Comment: Okay, so I leave my docker compose file like the above. Add your suggestion in the Dockerfile and then? Run docker-compose up?

Comment: You have to build your Docker image from the Dockerfile `docker build -t php:7.3-apache .` Then you can run `docker-compose up -d`